# Formulate mathematically H0 testing for interaction in type 1 ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

Given a type 1 ANOVA where both factors are fixed and with equal cell numbers, how do I mathematically formulate the $H_0$ testing for interaction effect? Let's say I have 3 levels of Factor A (rows) and 3 columns of factor B (columns).

I denote my interaction term in my model as $\gamma$

This is my take on my question:

$\gamma_{11}=\gamma_{12}=\gamma_{13}=\gamma_{21}=\gamma_{22}=\gamma_{23}=\gamma_{31}=\gamma_{32}=\gamma_{33}$

Does this seem right?